# Font changes in tools

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image]

There is some odd font sizing on the tools page (10k+ and mods).

Comment: I noticed that elsewhere also, can't remember where exactly. I'm not 10K.

Comment: @Pierre: Might be on some question lists too, I haven't checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have put in a fix, it will be in the next deployment. Thanks.